# I just don't understand why this won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, intervals

If you look at the very bottom of the script you can see the function interval(). the part that won't work is bc-(AEfficiency*100)/5; monz+((AEfficiency*100)/5)*((AFluency*AProduct)/100);
The values "bc" and "monz" aren't changing. Why? This change will occur after you've clicked "Generate Dealer" when running the html file. Pls help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sweetness Overload</title>
 <style>
  body{
   font-size:20px;
   margin:0;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
  #sweets{
   font-size:30px;
   position:fixed;
   top:1.0%;
   left:1.0%;
   text-align:center;
   user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select:none;
   -khtml-user-select:none;
   -webkit-user-select:none;
   -o-user-select:none;
  }
  #sweets:hover{
   text-decoration:underline;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  #sweetsMenu{
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   top:6.0%;
   left:0%;
   padding:0.5em 0.5em;
   text-align:left;
   vertical-align:top;
   background-color:lightgray;
   border:2px outset lightgray;
  }
  #sweetsMenu div{
   margin:0.0em 0em;
  }
  #sweetsMenu p{
   margin:0.5em 0em;
  }
  #dealers{
   font-size:30px;
   position:fixed;
   top:1.0%;
   right:1.0%;
   text-align:center;
   user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select:none;
   -khtml-user-select:none;
   -webkit-user-select:none;
   -o-user-select:none;
  }
  #dealers:hover{
   text-decoration:underline;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  #dealersMenu{
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   top:6.0%;
   right:0%;
   padding:0.5em 0.5em;
   text-align:left;
   vertical-align:top;
   background-color:lightgray;
   border:2px outset lightgray;
  }
  #dealersMenu div{
   margin:0.0em 0em;
  }
  #dealersMenu p{
   margin:0.5em 0em;
  }
  #cash{
   font-size:30px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:1.0%;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select:none;
   -khtml-user-select:none;
   -webkit-user-select:none;
   -o-user-select:none;
  }
  #cash:hover{
   cursor:default;
  }
  #click{
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
  }
  #click:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  #bc5{
   color:gray;
   float:right;
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
  }
  #AProperties{
   display:none;
   color:gray;
   float:right;
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33914917-1']);
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'dhmholley.co.uk']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

   (function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

 </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialise()">

<div id="blackBox2">
 <div id="blackBox"></div>
</div>

<div id="cash">
 <span id="monz"></span>
</div>

<div id="sweets" onclick="toggleSweets()">Sweets</div>

<div id="sweetsMenu">
 <div id="click" onclick="buyBC()">Bulk Candy (<span id="bccost"></span>)</div>
 <div id="txt"><span id="bc"></span> <span id="bc5"></span></div>
</div>

<div id="dealers" onclick="toggleDealers()">Dealers</div>

<div id="dealersMenu">
 <div id="click" onclick="genDeal()">Generate Dealer (<span id="crntdeal"></span>/<span id="maxdeal"></span>)</div>
 <div id="txt"><span id="dealerA"></span> <span id='AProperties'></span></div>
</div>

<script>
var monz = 10000;
 timer = 0;
 crntdeal = 0;
 maxdeal = 1;
 genEfficiency = 0;
 genFluency = 0;

 bccost = 1500;
 bcr = 180;
 bcp = 0;
 bc = 0;
 bc5 = bc * 5;
 bcprice = 500;

 dealerA = 'A';
 AEfficiency = 0;
 AFluency = 0;
 AProduct = bcprice;

function initialise(){
 getCash();
 getSweets();
 getDealers();
 setInterval(interval,25);
}

function getCash(){
 document.getElementById('cash').innerHTML = monz / 100 + "$";
}

function getSweets(){
 bc5 = bcp * 5;
 document.getElementById('bccost').innerHTML = bccost / 100 + "$";
 document.getElementById('bc').innerHTML = bc / 100 + "g";
 document.getElementById('bc5').innerHTML = bc5 / 100 + "g/sec";
}

function getDealers(){
 document.getElementById('crntdeal').innerHTML = crntdeal;
 document.getElementById('maxdeal').innerHTML = maxdeal;
 document.getElementById('dealerA').innerHTML = dealerA;
 document.getElementById('AProperties').innerHTML = (AProduct*AFluency)/100+"$/g"+" | "+AEfficiency+"g/sec";
}

function toggleSweets(){
 var sweetsMenu = document.getElementById('sweetsMenu');
 if (sweetsMenu.style.display != 'block'){
  sweetsMenu.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
  sweetsMenu.style.display = 'none';
 }
}

function toggleDealers(){
 var dealersMenu = document.getElementById('dealersMenu');
 if (dealersMenu.style.display != 'block'){
  dealersMenu.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
  dealersMenu.style.display = 'none';
 }
}

function buyBC(){
 if (monz >= bccost){
  monz = monz - bccost;
  bccost = bccost + bcr;
  bcr = bcr + 25;
  bcp += 4;
 }
}

function genDeal(){
 if (crntdeal < maxdeal){
  genEfficiency = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  genFluency = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  if (crntdeal == 0){
   AFluency = genFluency * 0.1 + 1;
   AEfficiency = genEfficiency;
   AProperties = document.getElementById('AProperties');
   AProperties.style.display = 'block';
  }
  crntdeal ++;
  getDealers();
 }
}

function interval(){
 timer ++;
 if (timer >= 8){
  bc += bcp
  if (bc >= (AEfficiency*100)/5){
   bc-(AEfficiency*100)/5;
   monz+((AEfficiency*100)/5)*((AFluency*AProduct)/100);
  }
  timer = 0;
 }

 getCash();
 getSweets();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your title should be a brief description of what isn't working, not your not being able to understand that something isn't working. Separately, you need to create an [mcve] rather than dumping all your code in the question. Note the "minimal" but also "complete" parts. Please also pay attention to the boxes in the snippet dialog, they're separated out for a reason.

Comment: Hello, your question is very easy , take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to

```
bc-=(AEfficiency*100)/5;
monz+=((AEfficiency*100)/5)*((AFluency*AProduct)/100);
```

you need the = in there to actually set the value.

Comment: Oh, yeah right... I just cam back to programming after a long break. I tried several error checkers but they didn't find it cause it isn't really an error¨

Comment: @RemovedByAdmin that's because there wasn't anything actually wrong with your code. you told it to do some math, and not save the answer. it would be like writing `bc=bc;` nothing wrong with that code, but it also won't do anything. If my answer helped you, it would be great if you could mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RemovedByAdmin Feel free to mark an answer as accepted if it best answers your question. Feel free to upvote anything you like.

Comment: @tylermackenzie Yeah, I know. Thx for the answer though, it really helped. It's a pain to forget such simple but important details